# How to use together!? Python, Lua, and Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, lua, 2d-games

I'm started programming not too long ago. I use a little of Python, Lua, and Ruby. Is it possible to compile all three scripts into one executable using py2exe, py2app, or py2deb?

If not, which one should I use for game development, and if anyone has any type of resources to study off of, I really would mind learning more.

Comment: Many games actually work by writing the main program in C (or C++ or ObjC or whatever), and embedding an interpreter to run scripts in. Embedding all three interpreters shouldn't be a problem at all (assuming you're willing to give each one its own main thread). It doesn't sound like that's what you're asking, given that you're talking about tools like `py2app`. It also ought to be possible to embed a Ruby or Lua interpreter in a Python C extension module, so you can do the same basic idea but without writing the top-level app in C. Does that sound interesting?

Comment: Do the scripts between languages need to communicate with each other?

Comment: Do you have any resources on how I can add Ruby and Lua interpreters in Python. I think that would be great to learn.

Comment: @user2967106: I've never actually embedded Ruby in anything, and Lua, not since… long before version 5.0, which cleaned everything up. So I wouldn't be much direct help. But look at projects like [Lunatic Python](http://labix.org/lunatic-python), which (IIRC) embeds Lua in a Python extension which a complete bridge between the two runtimes in only a few hundred lines of code. Even if you can't use it directly, the code must make good sample code.

Comment: Searching PyPI for [ruby](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=ruby) and [lua](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=lua) turns up some other interesting things like lupa and pyruby.

Comment: Yeah, there's also rubypython gem (a bridge to Python). I still consider it as a last-resort method, when you simply can't implement everything in one language (such as, you have a library in another language that your language does not have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining them all into one *executable* is hard. Combining them into one *application*, not so hard.

Let's take py2app as an example. It builds an OS X application bundle—a directory full of files. There's a complete Python interpreter with a custom standard library in the `Frameworks` subdirectory. And your application's Python source code (and/or .pyc bytecode) and all of your data files are in the `Resources` subdirectory. Finally, in the MacOS subdirectory, there are two things: a standard `python` stub executable, which runs Python with your custom standard library, and another stub executable with the name of your app, which runs Python with your custom standard library and executes your main script.

Imagine you had an identical tool for Ruby and Lua.

You could very easily build an application bundle that puts each framework in the `Frameworks` directory, puts all your source code in all three languages, and all of your data files, into the `Resources` directory, and puts all three stub executables in the `MacOS` directory. Whichever one of your scripts is the main program, you'd keep just the stub executable for that one.

As long as your scripts know how to find the python, lua, and ruby stub executables to launch other scripts (which you can do by, e.g., modifying the PATH in the environment at the start of your main script), everything works.

And there's an even simpler solution: `py2app` (and `ruby2app` and `lua2app`) up each application separately, and then just package the complete applications inside the bundle (e.g., in an `Applications` directory under the `Library` directory) and just run them that way. The down side is that if you have 20 different Python scripts, you're going to end up with 20 complete Python installations, which gets to be a pretty big download.

But you can go half-way in between: merge all the Python apps into one bundle, all the Ruby apps into another, and all the Lua apps into another.

The problem with doing this in practice are that you don't actually have an identical tool for Ruby and Lua; you have *different* tools, which build different structures. And you don't have an identical tool for Windows (`py2exe` builds a very differently-shaped structure, and uses very different configuration settings). So you need to understand (up to) the cartesian product of N*M different structures if you have N languages and M platforms.

And you really do need all the separate tools. `py2app` can't be used on Ruby or Lua code, or Windows code, because it needs to understand Python modules—including Python C extension modules, which it has to understand at the Mach-O level as well as at the Python API level—in order to figure out the dependencies and get the right files, and figure out the right places to put them in the bundle so the interpreter can find them, and so on.

Still, it's definitely doable—I've worked on two projects that bundled up multiple scripts written in two or three different scripting languages in exactly the way I described above.

Comment: "everything works"... slowly and inefficiently. (Nothing against your answer, I just think the OP's idea should be reconsidered with extreme prejudice.)

Comment: @Amadan: In what way is it slow and inefficient? It works _exactly_ the same as any app written in Python, Ruby, or Lua and distributed on its own.

Comment: Woah great answer. :)

Comment: Loading multiple language interpreters is certainly an inefficient use of memory, and will have an effect on speed as well.

Comment: @abarnert: What Mark said. Also, transporting data between the different interpreters, since they don't share the object space.

Comment: @MarkThomas: Well, yes, in the same sense that loading a single language interpreter uses memory and CPU time. Obviously if you can write everything in hand-optimized C, it will be faster than if you write it in Python or Lua. But the cost of running one Python process, one Ruby process, and one Lua process is no higher than the cost of running three Python processes—which is a common thing to do (as a performance optimization!) via, e.g., `multiprocessing`. And transporting data is basically the same as using `multiprocessing` except with a custom transport instead of `pickle`.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. It might be possible to use the JVM versions of the languages to create JVM classes, then JAR them up. I have never used any of them besides jRuby.
2. Why use three similar scripting languages at the same time? It's like eating pasta with mashed potatoes and bread.

Comment: They are very similar, but they have different pros and cons. I want to be able to choose what they are best at and build on that.